# Bad Request 400 when making a token request to Google gmail API

Tags: vb.net, oauth, google-api, token, bad-request

I follow this document to make token request https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

In the first step, it works fine. I can get the an authentication code.
In the second step, I have a problem with 400 Bad Request. I have been finding answer for this issue for 2 days, but I can't fix the problem. 
I set all the properties like the document, but it doesn't matter:

```
POST /oauth2/v3/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/v6xr77ewYqhvHSyW6UJ1w7jKwAzu&
client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=your_client_secret&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Here is my code:

```
    postData.Clear()
    ' code is the authentication code in the first request
    postData.Add("code=" + code)
    postData.Add("client_id=###############.apps.googleusercontent.com")
    postData.Add("client_secrect=####################")
    postData.Add("redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob")
    postData.Add("grant_type=authorization_code")

    Dim data As String = String.Join("&", postData.ToArray())
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token")
    Dim byteData() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)

    request.Host = "www.googleapis.com"
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteData.Length

    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    dataStream.Close()        

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim reader As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    response.Close()
```

Thanks for answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found a bug. This's a stupid bug. I typed client_secrect inteads of client_secret. I can't belive it took me 2 days to fix this error.